# Overload + operator for own class and std::string

Tags: c++

How to overload **+ operator** to be able to write something like this:

```
MyString str("He is");
str = str + " a cat";
```

MyString:

```
class MyString {
public:
    MyString();
    MyString(const char *text);
    MyString(const  MyString &stringToCopy);
    ~MyString();

    MyString& operator=(const  MyString &otherString); // It works
    MyString& operator=(const char *text); // It works
    MyString& operator+=(const MyString &otherString); // It works
    MyString& operator+=(const char *text); // It works
private:
    char *_chars;
    int _length;
};
```

My current idea (but it not works):

```
MyString operator+(MyString &firstString, std::string &text) {
    std::cout << "text: " << text << std::endl; // It not prints
    ...
}
```

I have no errors, but operator method is not calling.

```
cout << str.toStandard(); // Prints " cat". Without first char
```

**EDIT:**

I changed every std::string param to const char*

```
MyString MyString::operator+(const char *text) {
    MyString newString(*this);
    newString.pushText(text);

    cout << "test: " << newString.toStandard() << endl; // Prints correct append

    return newString;
}
```

And in main():

```
cout << (str + "teest").toStandard() << endl; // Not prints
```

In console I get error code: -1073741819

Comment: *How* it doesn't work? If you get compiler errors, copy and paste them into the question. We need [mcve] to able to help.

Comment: `" a cat"` is not a `std::string` though.

Comment: "*but operator method is not calling*": So are you getting a compiler error? If you are not getting a compiler error, then which overload is being called? Please provide a complete [repro].

Comment: `std::string &text` -> `const std::string& text` or `std::string_view text`

Comment: Now it' s a problem with returning value :(

Comment: You may be double-freeing the pointed text, but how do we know what your destructor is doing _without a minimal, complete, reproducible example_, again.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the `operator+` as follows:
`MyString MyString::operator+ (const MyString& strToAdd) const;`   or   `MyString MyString::operator+ (const std::string strToAdd) const;`

It's like the `+=` operator, but you create a new `MyString` and return it instead of appending it to the `MyString` object.

In my personal opinion it would be better that `operator+` is a member of `MyString`, but this works too:

```
MyString operator+ (const MyString& addStr, const std::string addStr2)
{
  MyString str(addStr);
  str += MyString(addStr2);
  return str;
}
```

Comment: Now it' s a problem with returning value :(
(info in edit)

Comment: Sorry, but I will upvote once you are const-correct :-) Also, explaining why you think it should be a member would be nice. Rather, as I see it, if something doesn't need to be a member, then it probably shouldn't be.

Comment: It's a bad habit of me, to do not use const modifiers. But thank you very much for helping to evolve my skills.

Comment: I personally think it's better, because i think it's a part of MyString as much asoperator+= and other operators are. I would search for it in the class MyString.